# Regular Expression Help Required for getting file name from path

Tags: regex, path, aem

I have the following requirements.
I have  the url's in format

```
/content/any-site-name(alphanumeric)/filename.css
```

It always starts with `/content` and the directory can be anything and could be any directory deep. The file extension will always be `.css`.

Need to write a regular expression to get the following path out of the entered path

```
/content/sitename/filename.css
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the difference between `any-site-name` and `sitename` ?

Comment: Could you show us some real examples?

Comment: @zessx Let me re iterate over the problem statement once again. What goes into the expression is a path e.g /content/mysite/folder1/folder2/filename.css or /content/mysite/filename.css or /content/mysite/folder1/filename.css. What should come out of the expression is a path /content/mysite/filename.css and should not show rest of the in between folder path between mysite and filename.css. Could you please help me with that. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to go from this:

```
/content/folder1/folder2/sitename/filename.css
```

to this:

```
/content/sitename/filename.css
```

and assuming the actual word "content" never changes,  you could try:

```
/\/content(\/[A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:[\/][^.]*)*([\/][a-zA-Z0-9]+.css)/
```

the match results will be $1:"/sitename", and $2: "/filename.css"  and then to get the desired string you simply add the parts you want together:
mystring  = "/content" + $1 + $2

Comment: Let me re iterate over the problem statement once again. What goes into the expression is a path e.g /content/mysite/folder1/folder2/filename.css or /content/mysite/filename.css or /content/mysite/folder1/filename.css. What should come out of the expression is a path /content/mysite/filename.css and should not show rest of the in between folder path between mysite and filename.css. Could you please help me with that. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thank You. This is what was exactly required. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression :

```
/content(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*/[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]css
```

[image: Regular expression in details]

Comment: Thanks for the help but let me re iterate over the problem statement once again. What goes into the expression is a path e.g /content/sitename/folder1/folder2/filename.css or /content/sitename/filename.css or /content/sitename/folder1/filename.css. What should come out of the expression is a path /content/sitename/filename.css. The current expression matches any path which we put in. Could you please help me with that. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @TechNiks : I didnt understand your problem. Can you update your question with your desired input and output ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for, if I undersood :

```
/\/content\/mysite\/(?:[\w-]+\/)*([\w-]+\.css)/
```

Works for :

- `/content/mysite/filename.css`
- `/content/mysite/folder1/filename.css`
- `/content/mysite/folder1/folder2/filename.css`
- `/content/mysite/folder1/folder2/folder3/filename.css`
- and so on...

[image]

[**Test this regex online**](http://regex101.com/r/aG2mX0)

Sample application ([php](/questions/tagged/php)) :

```
function getShortPath($url) {
    return preg_replace('/\/content\/mysite\/(?:[\w-]+\/)*([\w-]+\.css)/', '/content/mysite/$1', $url);
}

echo getShortPath('/content/mysite/filename.css').'<br>';
echo getShortPath('/content/mysite/folder1/filename.css').'<br>';
echo getShortPath('/content/mysite/folder1/folder2/filename.css').'<br>';
echo getShortPath('/content/mysite/folder1/folder2/folder3/filename.css').'<br>';
/*
/content/mysite/filename.css
/content/mysite/filename.css
/content/mysite/filename.css
/content/mysite/filename.css
*/
```

Note : you can improve this regex, by naming capturing groups :

```
/\/content\/(?<sitename>[\w-]+)(?<path>\/(?:[\w-]+\/)*)(?<filename>[\w-]+\.css)/
```

Then you'll have, as results :

- `/content/mysite/filename.css` :
  `{ sitename: "mysite", path: "/", filename: "filename.css" }`
- `/content/mysite/folder1/folder2/filename.css` :
  `{ sitename: "mysite", path: "/folder1/folder2/", filename: "filename.css" }`

[**Test this regex online**](http://regex101.com/r/qZ0lB7)

Comment: This capturing group method is great. Actually the mysite part has to be varying as well but got to learn a lot from your reg ex solution. Thanks a ton for the help :)